# Spring: Switching from web to mobile web (two independent projects)

Tags: spring, mobile, web

I currently have a Spring web application finished. What I want to do next is create a separate project (as requested) for the mobile web application. With some research, I've seen Spring mobile as a solution for this, but I'm not sure if this is the way to go since my two projects are independent of each other -- although, they'll be deployed in the same servlet container.

What's the best practice in proceeding with this? Should I use the Spring `DeviceResolverHandlerInteceptor` or should a simple Javascript redirect suffice?

Answer (score 0):

the principal difference between the javascript redirect and Spring Mobile is where the redirect is taking place; client or server side.  the javascript will do it after something has been rendered to the client.  this process can get expensive (and painful) when dealing with mobile clients.  (there's a great youtube video from google about speed and latency in mobile pages http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Il4swGfTOSM&feature=youtu.be)

so, i would recommend Spring Mobile for the following;
- it's done server side --> the client gets the 'right' page the 1st time
- it allows for granting the application 'client type' context (e.g. i'm getting this data for a mobile so only return 10 rows instead of the normal 100)
- it allows for expansion and clearer differentiation between mobile, tablet and desktop